# How to get The Member id from this Value? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello i need to get the Member id ive tried many things:

This is the Value: [<Member id=censored name='Spaffel' discriminator='0581' bot=False nick=None guild=>, <Member id=censored name='calvin.e.test' discriminator='1151' bot=False nick=None guild=>]

What is thy type of value called?

If i use this code to get the ids:

```
@client.command()
async def test123(ctx):
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) #i used the channel id but i removed it in this exampl
    members2 = voice_channel.members
    await ctx.send(f"User: {members2} ")

    for index, member in enumerate(members2):
        
        testlol = (id)
        await ctx.send(f"User: {testlol}  ")
```

I get this Output: User:

How can i get the id of the Member please help me :)

Comment: The value is called a list of [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) instances, you can iterate through them and use the [`id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.id) attribute

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of the members in a voice channel you can create a list and go through all the members in a voice channel.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def test123(ctx):
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID)
    members = voice_channel.members  # Members that are connected to the channel

    vcmember = []  # Creates a list
    for member in members:
        memids.append(member.id) # Get the IDs/add them to the list
        await ctx.send(f"{vcmember}")
```

! *Remember to import and activate Intents* !